# yiilite.php documentation is not available

Tags: php, yii, aptana3

Using Aptana Studio 3.0 (Eclipse based) I cannot see the documentation of functions, I only get this message:
yiilite.php documentation is not available.

Any idea how to sort this?

Comment: yiilite.php is a compressed version of Yii code, containing the same functions and classes - your IDE will get confused by duplicate class/function declarations. Look for ways to remove this file from your project.

Comment: And usually yiilite.php in IDE add to ignore files

Comment: @DCoder yiilite.php is not a 'compressed' version of Yii code. It is a file designed to replace yii.php in conjuction with PHP APC extension as it preloads commonly used classes so that they will be cached by APC. (You will notice the file is much larger than the default yii.php.) This (can) improve performance, but your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small amount of information on yiilite.php here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.performance